# Delay in looping of audio playback with Firefox and Chrome

Tags: html, audio

I have an one second audio `.wav` and `.ogg` files. Firefox has problem playing it in a loop. In 30sec it should play it 30 times but it can't. I have use the audio and embed tag to play the audio. Chrome sometime miss to play.

Comment: Could you include the audio files and the code you're using to play them, as well as clarify what you mean by 'miss to play'?

Comment: here is the example http://jsfiddle.net/nbhatti2001/JU8CP/